# Stadium Seats Python program need assistance to set amount with two decimal points

Tags: python

I have to correct this python program I am trying to set the dollar amounts to 2 decimal points. So far this is what i have done but still is not showing two decimal points!

Instructions are below:Python

"Write a program that asks how many tickets for each class of seats were sold, then displays the amount of income generated from ticket sales. There are three seating categories at the stadium. Class A seats costs $20, Class B seats cost $15, and Class C seats cost $10."

- Assume the user will enter valid data (Integer/Float).
- Declare Global variables, Local variables and Global constants as needed in the program
- Write and call function ShowIncome to calculate and display total income generated from ticket sales for all three Class seating categories.
- The program should round the amount of income generated from ticket sales to a maximum of two decimal places.

```
def calcIncome(n,c):
    if c=="A":
        return n * 20

    if c=="B":
        return n * 15

    if c=="C":
        return n * 10

def showIncome(a,b,c):
    total=a+b+c
    print("Income from class A seats:$",a)
    print("Income from class B seats:$",b)
    print("Income from class C seats:$",c)
    print("Total income:$",total)

def main():
    a=int(input("Enter count of A seats: "))
    b=int(input("Enter count of B seats: "))
    c=int(input("Enter count of C seats: "))

    aIncome=calcIncome(a,"A")
    bIncome=calcIncome(b,"B")
    cIncome=calcIncome(c,"C")

    showIncome(aIncome,bIncome,cIncome)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your 'showIncome' function:

```
def showIncome(a,b,c):
    total=a+b+c
    print("Income from class A seats:$",a)
    print("Income from class B seats:$",b)
    print("Income from class C seats:$",c)
    total = (round(float(total), 2))
    
    print("Total income:$","{:0,.2f}".format(total))
```

`(round(float(total), 2)))` -
This will round your total income into two decimal places after converting the value to 'float'.

Comment: @here2Grow remove the extra character at the end of the line. ```Total income:$",(round(float(total), 2)))```

Comment: i had to add another set of parenthesis to my program on another line so that was partially a reason why my program returned that error. Your suggestion did in fact work but it only showed one decimal place instead of 2.                                                                                   Enter count of A seats: 15
Enter count of B seats: 20
Enter count of C seats: 35
Income from class A seats:$ 300
Income from class B seats:$ 300
Income from class C seats:$ 350
Total income:$ 950.0 <---------- I also need to do the same with the income amounts as well.

Comment: @here2Grow my updated answer will resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the help i figured out the format to get the 2 decimal points i needed! {:,.2f}